# Inconsistency of definition of differentiation in Zorich.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, taylor-expansion

Zorich first define differentiable as
[image]

Thus, Zorich only requires a point to be a limit point that is in the domain. Many of the zorich's later theorem used this general definition. On the other hand, when proving Taylor's Theorem, zorich state the following:
[image]

In this paragraph $E$ is a **closed interval** with $x_0$ being one of its endpoints. The fact that the existence of $\phi^{(k)}(x_0)$ implies the the existence of $\phi^{(k-1)}(x)$ for $x$ in $E$ and $x$ close to $x_0$ requires the definition of differentiability to only consider the cases where $x_0$ is contained in some interval that is a subset of the domain. Note that this is even different from the classical definition which requires $x_0$ to be an interior point, since in this case $x_0$ is an endpoint of a closed interval.

Are there anyway to resolve these inconsistencies?

Comment: I don't see an inconsistency.  When considering a closed interval $E$ with $x_0$ an endpoint, $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$.  (And if you're going to get an error term at $x$ near $x_0$, $E$ will have to include the closed interval bounded by $x$ and $x_0$, so restricting Taylor's Theorem to closed intervals seems like a smart move.)

Comment: @Eric Towers The proof uses the fact that $\phi^{(k)}(x_0)$ exists implies $\phi^{(k-1)}(x)$ exists in the entirety of a closed interval containing $x_0$, which is not true if we were to consider limit point as differentiable

Comment: I'm still guessing at what the problem is.   In the definition you recite, $E$ is not required to be the domain of $f$; what is required is that $E$ is a subset of the domain and that $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$.  For the Taylor's theorem you recite, it is perfectly fine for $f$ to be defined on some set containing a closed interval, $E$, having $x_0$ as one endpoint -- then we are permitted to shrink that closed interval until all the derivatives we want are defined...